# Wrong timestamp value received from the ObjectId.getTimestamp() function

Tags: mongodb, datetime, timestamp, mongo-shell, objectid

I am currently learning MongoDB and while trying to explore the documentation I am encountering some anomaly while trying to use the ObjectId.getTimestamp() function. I executed the below is the lines of code at my machine's time 20:12. in mongo shell

```
    >x= new ObjectId()
    >ObjectId("5ac4e4362b7738556969dbba")
    >x.getTimestamp()
    >ISODate("2018-04-04T14:41:58Z")
```

I want to know why is there a different timestamp value being shown and not the exact timestamp when the Id was created ? Is it due to some UTC setting which should be done in a Mongo configuration file ?

Comment: Are you watching your machine time or server time? Because for me both shows same.. `MongoDB:PRIMARY> Date()
Wed Apr 04 2018 19:32:43 GMT+0300 (EEST)
MongoDB:PRIMARY> x= new ObjectId()
ObjectId("5ac4fe2d610c94d9f3c27391")
MongoDB:PRIMARY> x.getTimestamp()
ISODate("2018-04-04T16:32:45Z")
`

Comment: Ideally the machine time and the server time should be one and the 
  same. But here on my machine there is a difference in the machine 
  time and the server time and the same is evident in your comment 
  as well

Comment: Difference is only two seconds... What took time to execute those two first commands. Your question had 29 minutes difference (12 minutes vs. 41 minutes). Of course, hour value is different. First is GMT+3 and latter one is UTC (Zulu).